# Duplicated messages Using JSQMessagerViewController (Swift) (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, code-duplication, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I have a JSQMessagersViewController which is connected to a NavigationController. Moreover, I have a ViewController with a tableView with the contacts. Thus, when you click on a cell from the tableView, it opens the JSQMessagerViewController with that conversation. Inside the conversation, when the user sends a message the first time everything works fine. However, once the user goes out the conversation to the tableViewController, if he gets back in a conversation and sends a message, the message gets duplicated by the number of time the user when out and back in. In addition, once the message is duplicated and the user goes out of the conversation, once he click on the same conversation, the message is no longer duplicated. Indeed, when I verify on the database (Firebase), there is no duplicated messages. I can't figure out what is creating this loop.

MessageReceivedDelegate.swift

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

protocol MessageReceivedDelegate: class {
  func message_received(senderID: String, senderName: String, text: String, target: String)
}

class messages_help {

  private static let _instance = messages_help()
  weak var delegate: MessageReceivedDelegate?
  private var currentTarget = String()

  static var Instance: messages_help {
  return _instance
}

func sendMessage(senderID: String, senderName: String, text: String, target: String) {
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL: )
    let data: Dictionary <String, Any> = [Constants.sender_id: senderID, Constants.sender_name: senderName, Constants.text: text, Constants.target: target]
    ref.child("messages").childByAutoId().setValue(data)
}

func getData() {
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL: )
    let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
    let curr = ref.child("messages")
    curr.observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in
        //print(snapshot)
        //Get Value from DataBase
        print()
        if let data = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
            if let senderID = data[Constants.sender_id] as? String{
                if let senderName = data[Constants.sender_name] as? String {
                    if let target = data[Constants.target] as? String{
                        if user?.uid == senderID || user?.email == target{
                            if let text = data[Constants.text] as? String {
                                self.delegate?.message_received(senderID: senderID, senderName: senderName, text: text, target: target)
                              }
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
       },withCancel: nil)
    }
  }
}
```

ChatViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import JSQMessagesViewController
import MobileCoreServices
import AVKit
import FirebaseAuth

class ChatViewController: JSQMessagesViewController, 
MessageReceivedDelegate {

@IBOutlet var targetLabel: UINavigationItem!
var messages = [JSQMessage]()
@IBOutlet var chatLabel: UINavigationItem!
var i = 0

var targetEmail = String()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
    messages_help.Instance.delegate = self
    self.senderId = user?.uid
    self.senderDisplayName = user?.email
    self.targetLabel.title = targetEmail
    setupBackButton()

    // Show Button to simulate incoming messages

    self.inputToolbar.contentView.leftBarButtonItem = nil

    if Language().check_language() == "Fr"{
        self.inputToolbar.contentView.textView.placeHolder = "Nouveau message";
    }
    else if Language().check_language() == "Es"{
        self.inputToolbar.contentView.textView.placeHolder = "Nuevo mensaje";
    }
    self.inputToolbar.contentView.rightBarButtonItem.setImage(UIImage(named: "paper_plane"), for: .normal)
    self.inputToolbar.contentView.rightBarButtonItem.setTitleColor(UIColor.brown, for: .normal)

    automaticallyScrollsToMostRecentMessage = true

    //self.collectionView?.reloadData()

    //messages_help.Instance.getData()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    messages.removeAll()
    messages_help.Instance.getData()
}

func go() {

    let toViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "previous") as! PreviousRequestsViewController
    //Go to the page
    self.present(toViewController, animated:true, completion: nil)
}


//message received
func message_received(senderID: String, senderName: String, text: String, target: String) {
    if target == targetEmail || senderName == targetEmail {
        //print("Number of loop\n")
        //i = i+1
       // print(i)
        /**
         *  Scroll to actually view the indicator
         */
        self.scrollToBottom(animated: true)
    messages.append(JSQMessage(senderId: senderID, displayName: senderName, text: text))
    }
    collectionView.reloadData()
}

// Number of rows
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return messages.count
}

// Cell 
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = super.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAt: indexPath) as! JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell
    return cell
}

// Display messages
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, messageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> JSQMessageData! {
    return messages[indexPath.item]
}
// Avatar
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, avatarImageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource! {
    return JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory.avatarImage(with: UIImage(named: "iTunesArtwork"), diameter: 30)
}


//the bubble
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: JSQMessagesCollectionView!, messageBubbleImageDataForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath!) -> JSQMessageBubbleImageDataSource! {
    let bubble_fact = JSQMessagesBubbleImageFactory()
    let message = messages[indexPath.item]
    if message.senderId == self.senderId {
        return bubble_fact?.outgoingMessagesBubbleImage(with: UIColor.brown)
    }
    else {
        return bubble_fact?.incomingMessagesBubbleImage(with: UIColor.darkGray)
    }
}

// When pressed sent
override func didPressSend(_ button: UIButton!, withMessageText text: String!, senderId: String!, senderDisplayName: String!, date: Date!) {

    messages_help.Instance.sendMessage(senderID: senderId, senderName: senderDisplayName, text: text, target: self.targetEmail )

    //dismiss text from text fild
    finishSendingMessage()
}

func setupBackButton() {

    if Language().check_language() == "Fr"{
     let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Retour", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(backButtonTapped))
        backButton.tintColor = UIColor.brown
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
    }
    else if Language().check_language() == "Es"{
    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Regresa", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(backButtonTapped))
        backButton.tintColor = UIColor.brown
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
    } else {
    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(backButtonTapped))
        backButton.tintColor = UIColor.brown
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
    }
}

func backButtonTapped() {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
}
```

ContactChatViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

 class ContactChatViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {

@IBOutlet var chat_TableView: UITableView!

var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!
var publish = [String?]()
var data_to_send = String()
var encountered = Set<String>()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL: )
    getDataa()
}

// get data from trips
func getDataa() {

    // Reference to current user
    let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser
    let curr = ref.child("messages")
    curr.observe(.childAdded, with: {(snapshot) in
        if let data = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let use = messages()
            use.setValuesForKeys(data)

            //Append new data if same user
            if user?.email == use.target || user?.email == use.sender_name {
                if self.encountered.contains(use.sender_name!) || (user?.email)! == use.sender_name! {
                    //print("Already inside")
                } else {
                    self.encountered.insert(use.sender_name!)
                    self.publish.append(use.sender_name)
                }
                //Appen to to array even if current user sent a message but is not the target
                if user?.email == use.sender_name{
                    if self.encountered.contains(use.target!) {
                        print("Already inside")
                    } else {
                        self.encountered.insert(use.target!)
                        self.publish.append(use.target)
                    }
                }
            }
            //Load data in U Thread
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.chat_TableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
        ,withCancel: nil)
}


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    // hide separators
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    //return count with database
    return publish.count
}

// Assign rows a value
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell_user = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "previous_cell")
    cell_user.selectionStyle = .none
    cell_user.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    cell_user.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.brown
    cell_user.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25)

    // Check for duplicates

    cell_user.textLabel?.text = self.publish[indexPath.row]



    return cell_user
}

//Clicked on a cell
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    data_to_send = self.publish[indexPath.row]!
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "chatSegue", sender: self)

    //let chatView = ChatViewController()
    //chatView.targetEmail = self.publish[indexPath.row]!
    //let chatNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: chatView)
    //present(chatNavigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    //let toViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "chatPage") as! ChatViewController

    //toViewController.targetEmail = data_to_send
    //Go to the page
    //self.present(toViewController, animated:true, completion: nil)

    let navVC = segue.destination as? UINavigationController
    let chatVC = navVC?.viewControllers.first as! ChatViewController
    chatVC.targetEmail = data_to_send
}

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning() 
  }
}
```

Comment: Hard to figure out without seeing some code

Comment: I just added the codes

Comment: I too made a chatting app using firebase initially duplicate message appeared in my project was because I was using a array to get all the messages from server. while chatting through firebase the function which is used to get the message is continuously referred so while each time you get a message and the handler of DB to get message is called just do one thing like if u using array make it array.removeall() in start of the function and if u using a string like message = string() . then before the function in called make it equal to nil this will solve your duplicate message problem

Comment: I have the messages.removeall() right before the messages_help.Instance.getData() in viewDidLoad() but it is not doing anything. Where do you suggest I put it at ?